# Update Column with row number

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an temp table table in SQL Server stored Procedure with a Id and date column. The table is already populated with dates and I want to be able to add a sequence number in the id column based on the dates in ascending order

I have tried the following

```
UPDATE #Weeks 
SET Id = (
          SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY WeekDate ASC) AS Id 
          FROM #Weeks AS DATA);
```

and get this error.

Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Any help is appreciated.

This worked for me.....

UPDATE #Weeks 
SET Id = tab.Id
FROM #Weeks w
     INNER JOIN (
                 SELECT WeekDate,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY WeekDate ASC) AS Id 
                 FROM #Weeks ) Tab ON w.WeekDate = Tab.WeekDate

Comment: **Update Column with row number** ? it's not good idea!

Comment: @mehdi What is a good idea?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE #Weeks 
SET Id = Tab.Id
FROM #Week w
     INNER JOIN (
                 SELECT Id, 
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY WeekDate ASC) AS Id 
                 FROM #Weeks ) Tab ON w.Id = Tab.Id
```

As the sub-query returns more than one row, and = operator for only one row.

Comment: UPDATE #Weeks 
SET Id = tab.Id
FROM #Weeks w
     INNER JOIN (
                 SELECT WeekDate,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY WeekDate ASC) AS Id 
                 FROM #Weeks ) Tab ON w.WeekDate = Tab.WeekDate

Comment: I have edited the original question and posted the answer that worked for me ....hawk had pointed me in the right direction, thanks again

Comment: @realnumber3012 Was not copy-past, was just missing a character.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
;with cte as
(
SELECT Id,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY WeekDate ASC) AS DATA FROM #Weeks 
)

UPDATE #Weeks SET Id=DATA from cte
```

Comment: try it one last time!!

Comment: I think this is a good direction. But, I would write it like this:
;WITH CTE AS
(
 SELECT WeekDate, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY WeekDate ASC) AS NewId FROM #Weeks 
)

UPDATE [UPDATEWeeks] 
SET [UPDATEWeeks].[Id] = CTE.[NewId] 
FROM #Weeks AS [UPDATEWeeks] 
INNER JOIN CTE ON CTE.[WeekDate] = [UPDATEWeeks].[WeekDate];

Answer (score 0):

```
  UPDATE #Weeks 
    SET Id = t.Id1
    FROM #Week w
    INNER JOIN
    (
      SELECT Id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY WeekDate ASC) AS Id1 
      FROM #Weeks ) T ON w.Id = t.Id
```